# Mongo update multiple fields of an object which is inside an array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Using Mongo findOneAndUpdate, I am trying to update just some fields in an object from array of objects.

My object:

```
mainObject:{
    _id: '123',
    array:[
        {title:'title' , name:'name', keep:'keep'},        
        {title:'title', keep:'keep'},
    ]
}
```

I want to change `title` and `name` for the first object in array, and keep the `keep` field unchanged.
This is my closest approach using [Positional Operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/):

```
// here i set dynamic arguments for query update
// sometimes i need to update only one field, sometime i need to update more fields
// also, is there a better way to do this?

let title
let name

 if (args.title) {
      title = { title: args.title };
    }
 if (args.name) {
      name= { name: args.name};
    }


db.Test.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: args.id, 'mainObject.array.title': args.title},
        {
          $set: {
            'mainObject.array.$[]': {
              ...title,
              ...name
              }
          }
      }
 )
```

this problem is that it replace the whole object, the result is:

```
mainObject:{
    array:[
        {title:'changed' , name:'changed'},     //without keep...    :(
        {title:'title', keep:'keep'},
    ]
}
```

Should I use aggregation framework for this?

Comment: Aggregation queries can't write back to same collection, their main purpose is for querying not updating back, though there are two stages `$out` -- will overwrite the collection if existing or create a new & `$merge` - will write to new collection or create new (These two are not what we're looking at), So it has to be a normal update process.

Comment: @srinivasy, noted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to be like this :

```
db.test.findOneAndUpdate({'mainObject.array.title': 'title'},
{$set : {'mainObject.array.$.title':'changed','mainObject.array.$.name': 'changed'}})
```

From your query, `$` will update the first found element in array that matches the filter query, if you've multiple elements/objects in `array` array then you can use `$[]` to update all of those, let's see your query :

```
'mainObject.array.$[]': {
              ...title,
              ...name
              }
```

Major issue with above query is that it will update all the objects in `array` array that match the filter with below object :

```
{
    ...title,
    ...name
}
```

So, it a kind of replace entire object. Instead use `.` notation to update particular values.

Comment: So, i can use positional operator multiple times! Thanks!